# Delete general old & bad-rated questions?

Tags: feature-request

Some people ask bad or very personal questions (asking for code for example).

Would be great if we could delete them automatically if they have a bad number of votes (-20 maybe?)

Stackoverflow would have only the important and outstanding questions.

Comment: we already delete a lot of stuff auto-magically: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that